# XCode Compile Error errno=22

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode6

All,

I am having trouble compiling an old project I saved to dropbox, and then downloaded to my computer after a hard drive wipe. I believe I have installed all appropriate frameworks again, but am met with the following error:

```
Ld /Users/jclark/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/RMAPS_Fire-axrgcesnhsncrjgrcnvuslkdxshc/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/RMAPS\ FireTests.xctest/RMAPS\ FireTests normal x86_64
cd "/Users/jclark/Desktop/RMAPS Fire v.1"
export IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET=7.1
export PATH="/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang -arch x86_64 -bundle -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator8.2.sdk -L/Users/jclark/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/RMAPS_Fire-axrgcesnhsncrjgrcnvuslkdxshc/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator -F/Users/jclark/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/RMAPS_Fire-axrgcesnhsncrjgrcnvuslkdxshc/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator -F/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/Library/Frameworks -F/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator8.2.sdk/Developer/Library/Frameworks -filelist /Users/jclark/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/RMAPS_Fire-axrgcesnhsncrjgrcnvuslkdxshc/Build/Intermediates/RMAPS\ Fire.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/RMAPS\ FireTests.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/RMAPS\ FireTests.LinkFileList -bundle_loader /Users/jclark/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/RMAPS_Fire-axrgcesnhsncrjgrcnvuslkdxshc/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/RMAPS\ Fire.app -Xlinker -objc_abi_version -Xlinker 2 -framework XCTest -fobjc-arc -fobjc-link-runtime -Xlinker -no_implicit_dylibs -mios-simulator-version-min=7.1 -framework UIKit -framework Foundation -Xlinker -dependency_info -Xlinker /Users/jclark/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/RMAPS_Fire-axrgcesnhsncrjgrcnvuslkdxshc/Build/Intermediates/RMAPS\ Fire.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/RMAPS\ FireTests.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/RMAPS\ FireTests_dependency_info.dat -o /Users/jclark/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/RMAPS_Fire-axrgcesnhsncrjgrcnvuslkdxshc/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/RMAPS\ FireTests.xctest/RMAPS\ FireTests

ld: can't map file, errno=22 file'/Users/jclark/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/RMAPS_Fire-axrgcesnhsncrjgrcnvuslkdxshc/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/RMAPS Fire.app' for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

I have checked that this is an appropriate path and have search the site and found similar errors but cannot seem to resolve this one on my own. Any help is appreciated.

XCode version 6.2 (using Mavericks)

Comment: It's complaining that it can't access your app while trying to build a test bundle for it.  Have you checked whether the referenced file actually exists?  If so, check what architecture the referenced file was built for.

Comment: The file exists, see http://imgur.com/Cuv5DyC,xnEDWAp#0. I have also included a screenshot of the architectures. How could I check that this file is of a certain architecture?

Comment: One way is to use "lipo -info <file>" from the command line on the binary file that's inside your .app package.  (On the command line, the .app is just another directory.)

Comment: Is there any fix yet?

Comment: Hey, find a fix? i am stuck on this too